# Using Alias to model bidirectional constraints in GAMS

Tags: optimization, alias, gams-math

I'm working on a big optimization problem on GAMS so it's impossible for me to put the entire code here but I hope you could help me with where I am stuck at. I have 4 power nodes in my model that are connected by 2 bidirectional transmission lines (r) like this.
[image]

where r_a, r_b are the current transmission line capacities. Power can flow both directions and I'm tracking power going from A to A' and B to B' as well as from A' to A and B' to B. **So there are 4 power flows (f) in 2 transmission lines (r)**. My decision variables are how much capacity upgrade (c(f)) I need to build in each of these lines to satisfy more power flow needs. So in GAMS, I minimized the cost of upgrading as:

```
investment_cost..         cap_cost =e= sum(f,c(f)*capCost(f));
```

here capCost(f) is the capital cost of upgrading the transmission line capacity to be able to flow 1 extra GW her hour.

My constraint: In each time period (t), the total power flow p(f,t) must be less than or equal to the existing line capacity + newly upgraded capacity:

```
line_cap(f,t).. old_line_cap(l)+c(f) =g= p(f,t);
```

However, my solution looks something like this:

- **fAA': 6.7**  (built 6.7 GW more of capacity in line from A to A')
- **fA'A: 5.0** (built 5.0  GW more of capacity in line from A' to A)
- **fBB': 5.5** (built 5.5 GW more of capacity in line from B to B')
- **fB'B: 8.1** (built 8.1 GW more of capacity in line from B' to B)

But this is not right because if I upgrade line AA' by 6.7 GW, I don't need to upgrade line A'A, since they are the same line. Basically, I pay twice to upgrade the same line.

So I fix this, I'm trying to use Alias such as this:

```
Alias(f,ff)
line_cap(f,t)..   old_line_cap(f)+c(f)+ sum((f,ff)$[line_source(f)=line_sink(ff) and line_source(ff)=line_sink(f)],c(ff)) =g= p(f,t);
```

But that still does not fix my problem.

I'd appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: Can you edit your problem a little bit and answer a couple questions:  How can you have 2 independent power flows in one wire, `r`?  Do you mean that power can flow in both directions (seems reasonable) or are there 2 physical independent conductors for each connection?  Specifically, how do you have 2 non-linked flows between `A` and `A'`?  Why are you labeling nodes with primes?  Why isn't this `A, B, C, D`?  Is there some relationship that is not explained?  How is `r` related to `f`?  Can you describe the set `f` in the context of your example?

Comment: @AirSquid sorry for not being more clear. r are the lines (2) and f are the flows in those 2 lines of both directions (so 4 f). A and A' are just names of the nodes that are connected by 1 line r.  They can be named differently ABCD etc. 

So I have 2 lines r (r_a and r_b) that are the 2 lines that connect A and A' and B and B'. And f are the flows between these lines. So f can be flows from A to A', from A' to A, from B to B' and from B' to B. But r are just the lines.

Comment: So, now I'm more confused.  If there is only 1 physical wire between the nodes, you only have 1 flow.  It can go either way, but there is only one flow.  You are getting into trouble here because you are modeling 1 thing with 2 variables.  Just use +/- convention and then 2 constraints for capacity, `f<=capacity` and `-f<=capacity` so that flow in either direction is constrained.

Comment: @AirSquid yes normally I would do that, but I inherited the model from someone else and if I model 1 variable it would mess up other constraints that I would not wish to get into, so I'm wondering if theres a way I can fix this as it is (modeling 2 variables). Do you think it would work if I restrict fA'A = fAA' and fB'B = fBB' and divide the cost in half?

Comment: without reviewing the whole model, it is tough to advise.  One thing for certain, is that fA'A = -fAA'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with your 4 `f`s, let's call them your virtual lines (since a pair of two of these virtual lines actually form one physical lines). Now, let's introduce a new set of physical lines (`fPhys`) and a mapping between the virtual and the physical lines (`fMap`):

```
Set fPhys          / fAA, fBB /
    fMap(f, fPhys) / ("fA'A", "fAA'").fAA
                     ("fB'B", "fBB'").fBB /;
```

Now, you can stick with using the set `f` for your flows, and use `fPhys` for the investment decision, like this:

```
investment_cost..         cap_cost =e= sum(fPhys,c(fPhys)*capCost(fPhys));

line_cap(f,t).. sum(fMap(f,fPhys), old_line_cap(fPhys)+c(fPhys)) =g= p(f,t);
```